# Mysql bindValue won't work as espected

Tags: qt, qt4

I am having a problem when i try updating a table using mysql but works in sqlite3 and postgres 8.4.9

```
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("UPDATE logs SET free=:_free,full=:_full WHERE id=:id");
    qry.bindValue(":id", 1);
    qry.bindValue(":_free", free);
    qry.bindValue(":_full", full);
    qry.exec();
```

I have read here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qmysql about what the docs have said about mysql but i need to know how my query changes to work in mysql.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the names don't match. In you query you have `:free_trial` and `:full_license`, but the bound variables are `:free` and `:full`.

Comment: that must have been a typo.In an example i tried last night,i could select and view records in mysql but i couldn't update or insert the same way i was doing in sqlite or postgres.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What does `exec()` return? What does `q.lastError()` contain?

Comment: I didn't both with the lastError since it could select the data in the server.The mysql driver was made three years ago,someone gave it to me.

Comment: If it works with SQlite then it's a problem with your MySql driver. Try to find a new version or a better supported one.